# C# Optional params for build sql string best way

Tags: c#, sql-server

i'm trying to see which is the best way or practise for sql string optimizations in c#, mssql. What i'm trying to do is like a crud system where we send the necessary required params such as db name and table and after we have the conditional, for example if its a remove action, we will have an where condition and it can contain more than 1 param so what i wanna know is get the whole params.

Should i accept an array with those conditions or what i must do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer to your question but you should consider using ORM tool like NHibernate.

With NHibernate, you can accept `QueryCriteria` or `ICriteria` from outside world which will do the query accordingly.

Be warned that this will be big change in your application and NHibernate have steep learning curve.

There are also simple micro-ORMs available like Dapper. With it, you can implement Repository pattern by creating Data Access Layer. Refer [this](https://github.com/timschreiber/DapperUnitOfWork/tree/master/DapperUnitOfWork) link.

Comment: As an addition, I would note LINQ - which allows queries to be composed via expressions against `IQueryable<T>` - ties into ORMs like EF and L2S. Personally I tent to just use dapper, though :)

Comment: for example, if i wanna get a thing from a db named hi, which table is hello and the where is id = xd , this case will just contain 1 where clausule. Now we are gonna access it like mssql_delete(dbname,tablename,condition1) but what if i wanna add more? that's the point ,i wanna know the best handling way.